# Comparing two files content wise without sorting them

Tags: python, bash, file, comparison

`test1.txt` has content as below:

```
Hi, how are you ?
It's already late.
My name is Sayan.
```

`test2.txt` has content as below:

```
My name is Sayan.
It's already late.
Hi, how are you ?
```

In my scenario, both of the files are equal content wise.

I want to create a script (basically without using `sort`, `comm`, `cmp`, `diff`) that will compare these two files, `test1.txt` and `test2.txt`, content wise and produce a result:

```
File Comparison status - Success
```

or if contents are different then

```
File Comparison status - Failed  [ check in result.txt ]
```

where `result.txt` will have that extra or missing or modified content listed.

Script could be in Bash or/and in Python. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly wrap up your code in CODE TAGS by using `{}` button while editing your post. Also add your efforts too what you have tried to solve this problem too.

Comment: Why do you limit yourself to not use these very handy tools?

Comment: This would involve implementing the functionality of both `sort` and `diff`, which makes this question very broad. I suggest you try to start solving this, and when you run into a specific problem, come back and ask a question about that specific problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are not too big, you could use `sorted()` to sort the lines and compare the resulting lists. To produce a diff of the files' contents you can use the [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html) module:

```
import difflib    

with open('file1') as f1, open('file2') as f2:
    f1_lines = sorted(f1)
    f2_lines = sorted(f2)

    if f1_lines == f2_lines:
        print("Equal so far")

    f2_lines.append("Extra line\n")

    print("".join(difflib.unified_diff(f1_lines, f2_lines)))
```

Output:

```
Equal so far
--- 
+++ 
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 Hi, how are you ?
 It's already late.
 My name is Sayan.
+Extra line
```